# Deleting multiple variables each pass of a loop

Tags: python

In the main loop of my program, I have around a dozen variables that are calculated each time the loop is actioned. At this stage I would prefer a 'NameError' than to have the variables from an earlier pass affect the outcome of a future pass of the loop.

Right now I just have a series of the following statements run at the final step of each loop:

```
try:
    del my_var1
except:
    pass
```

I suspect there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `dict` instead of bare variable names:

```
while True:
    data = dict()
    data['my_var1'] = ...
```

Each time through the loop, `data = dict()` will clear all the keys.

Comment: Although I need to go back and change some lines of code, this seems to me to be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the loop body in a function:

```
def _f(i):
    lots of code with many variables here

for i in range(20):
    _f(i)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with the early testing stage I'm at (too many returns), however this is probably very similar to how I'll do things once I'm further along.